# Installing a new drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

New to Linux.   Managed to install a new mechanical drive that I can access through my home directory 8 tb.  ChatGPT walked me through it.   Then attempted to install another drive this time a 4tb SSD using the same process.   Got partitions removed and got it mounted fine.   All looks well in lsblk.   Edited fstab with the same line that worked for the installation of the mechanical disk but the drive will not show up in my home directory.      /dev/sdc1 /mnt/4TBSSD ext4 defaults 0 0  Any advice appreciated.  It is NOT a dual boot system.

Comment: `/mnt` is outside your home directory and mount-points under it wont show under your home directory by default.

Comment: Post: `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -f` so we can see details. Some SSD need firmware update, do you have latest firmware? Compare `udisksctl status` to revision on vendors web site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're expecting but you could just use it at `/mnt/4TBSSD`. Or if you prefer, mount it to `/home/yourself/mybigdisk` instead.

It won't show up as something like `C:` and `D:` on Windows, but just as a directory with much space to use at the place you mount it to.

Gnome's disks program can help you with mounting, or you can just edit `/etc/fstab` again.